Make surface wrap it's child while also adjusting itself to max height or width of the parent
I have an (3)image on a (2)surface which is inside a (3)box. I need the surface to wrap itself around the child image with some padding, and occupy max height or width depending in the dimensions of the image while adjusting the other dimension such that there is even padding all round the image. In the screenshot below the height on the surface should be smaller, so that the padding around the image is even on all sides
Box(modifier=modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
    {
        Surface(
            shadowElevation = 8.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = image),
                contentDescription = description,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize().fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(32.dp)
            )

        }
    }


In the code if I remove fillMaxSize() from modifier, the image becomes small.
Box(modifier=modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
    {
        Surface(
            shadowElevation = 8.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = image),
                contentDescription = description,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                    .padding(32.dp)
            )

        }
    }
}


